# "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable" using PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Im trying to apply the logarithmic mapping using PIL but i got the error `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

My code is:

```
from PIL import Image
import math

photo = Image.open('TurtleLuminance.jpg')
data = photo.getdata()
c = 255 / math.log(1+255)
logarithmic = [int(c * math.log(1+data[x][0]) + c * math.log(1+data[x][1]) + c * math.log(1+data[x][2])) for x in range(len(data))]

gray_image = Image.new('L', photo.size)
gray_image.putdata(logarithmic)
gray_image.save('TurtleLogarithmic.jpg')
photo.close()
gray_image.close()
```

Someone could help me?

Comment: Can you share the complete error message? in which line the error happens?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's the deal, i tried your code and found out it worked the first time, but not the second time, this happend because the second time it has a level of grey image, so his pixels value is a single integer, where as the other ones were tuples (R,G,B). so perhaps you should check if the pixel is an int(p), and if it is convert it to a tuple p = (p,p,p)

```
 if type(p) == int:
      p = (p,p,p)
```